# Set subscription once at time of mounting and do not refresh it on every update?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following firebase subscription being created with `useEffect` in a simple functional component:

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection('chatChannels').doc('general')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          setMessages(snapshot.data().messages);
        } else {
          console.log('it was empty');
        }
      })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });
```

This is intended to retrieve the content of the `messages` field off the `general` document in the `chatChannels` collection. I'm trying to set up a simple instant messaging public channel, in other words.

The issue is I find this is problematic for performance. Anytime a message is sent, state is updated, the subscription is canceled, `useEffect` triggers, and the subscription is recreated. It's a lot of unnecessary network roundtrips. I would like to avoid that. But I can't think of a way to set this up such that a new message updates state *without* remaking the subscription every time.

I do want to unsubscribe when the component is entirely unmounted, but not every time it updates. It's unclear to me whether that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an empty dependency `[]` to the `useEffect` hook and it'll behave `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection('chatChannels').doc('general')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          setMessages(snapshot.data().messages);
        } else {
          console.log('it was empty');
        }
      })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Here is a link to the official `useEffect` documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects